# why isn't rails (or script/console) seeing my current version of 'gem'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm having trouble getting a working rails console, and I'm not sure why. I've tried to distil  my issue and the console output below sums it up :

---

**capistrano@dev:/webapps/cts/current$** ./script/console

Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.4)
Rails requires RubyGems >= 1.3.2 (you have 1.3.0). Please '`gem update --system`' and try again.

**capistrano@dev:/webapps/cts/current$** gem --version

1.3.5

Comment: Have you tried it? gem update --system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have gem installed in 2 different places, and the user Rails is running as has a different default path than your user, so it is finding a different version of gem.

Comment: It turns out that when I installed REE on my ubuntu machine, I updated *most* of the ruby related executables, but I missed 'rake' and 'irb'. I had added REE/bin to the path of my personal user, not everyone (ie: capistrano) so that was another gotcha.  Thanks for the pointer.